# HTML tag change position

Tags: php, html

I have a html structure like below, I want to place my custom header at a random position.

```
  <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
         <?php echo do_shortcode('[header]'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="div3"></div>
  </div>
```

But it always make my header go to the bottom.

```
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
         //I want the header to stay here 
      </div>
      <div class="div3"></div>
      <header>......</header>
  </div>
```

However I place it, the header always go to the bottom, please give advice if you experience it.

UPDATE:
In my case, a specific class removed helped. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Is javascript turned off and you sure you edit the right file?

Comment: @caramba, I'm using Wordpress and it is not turned off. Do you think it might happen because of js? there's so many files in theme so I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the response of the PHP echo? It may contains a "</div>", this should be the reason.

Comment: Well it looks right what you do. So it could either be you edit the wrong file or javascript or what @DiabloSteve says.

Comment: Thanks guy, I'm not sure the shortcode contains any close div before opening it but it most likely the problem, I still trying to reappend but haven't solved it.